# I'm not able to find model with two ids

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm not able to find the two '_id's highlighted below at a time

My messages collection from database is shown below
[image]

I want to verify those highlighted "_id"s to find whether those users are there in the messages collection or not.

Here is my code. If there is no such collection with those 2 user ids, it will create a new one, else it will show the collection

```
exports.send = (req, res) => {
  let { id } = req.body;
  messages.findOne(
    {
      " user1._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.User._id),
      "user2._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
    },

    (err, found) => {
      if (err || !found) {
        messages.findOne(
          {
            " user1._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
            "user2._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.User._id),
          },

          async (err, found) => {
            if (err || !found) {
              let message = new messages({
                user1: await getuser(req.User._id),
                user2: await getuser(id),
              });
              await message.save((err, saved) => {
                if (err) {
                  return res.json(err);
                } else {
                  return res.json(saved);
                }
              });
            } else {
              console.log("2nd else");
             return res.json(found);
            }
          }
        );
      } else {
        console.log("1st else");
        return res.json(found);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Here 'req.User' comes from a middleware called 'isSignedIn', the 'id' comes from frontend.

I'm always getting a new 'messages' collection instead of showing the collection which is there.All these collections are with same user1 and user2.

I'm getting the result when I find with one user id, but I'm getting null when I find with two user ids

this is working

```
messages.findOne({ "user1._id":new ObjectId(id)})
```

this is not working

```
messages.findOne({ "user1._id":new ObjectId(id), "user2._id": new ObjectId(req.User._id)})
```

Comment: Can you little describe your model? I mean snap of your model.

Comment: im getting undefined in `messages.findById`

Comment: Read the documentation for the `findById` method https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById tthe first argument to that function is an id not an object. Have you tried `messages.findById(req.User._id)`???

Comment: If collection name is user1 then use like `messages.findById({_id: req.User._id})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working, I took 2 days to find my mistake.

you can see there is a gap in  user1._id, that's my mistake. There shouldn't be gap

```
" user1._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
```

only this method is working

```
messages.findOne({ "user1._id":new ObjectId(id), "user2._id": new ObjectId(req.User._id)})
```

And this is not working

```
 messages.findOne(
    {
      user1: { _id: new ObjectId(req.User._id) },

      user2: { _id: new ObjectId(id) },
    },
```